# Is "screen" better than "nohup"?

Tags: linux

nohup and screen both does the similar job. But, I want to know why **screen** is being preferred over **nohup** command in linux?

Comment: You can reattach to screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`screen` is good for interactive processes, where you might need to detach and reattach a vtty.  `nohup` is best for unattended processes like userspace daemons or processes you will check on later.